# fadeIn and fadeOut not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

In my code i've few images and i've tried to show them as slider so when a clickme button clicked the image will be change to next image.I  have succssfully done this fucntion but i want animation ,when i click clickme button then current image should fadeOut and next image should be fadeIn,
I'm unable to do this,

```
   $('#allimg li:first').addClass('activeimg');
  //code for like and next image  
   $('.clickme').on('click', function() {
    var tagname = $('.activeimg img').attr('name');
    if ( $('#allimg li.activeimg').index() + parseInt(1) !== $('#allimg li').length ) {
        $('.activeimg').removeClass('activeimg').fadeIn().next('#allimg li').addClass('activeimg').fadeOut();
       }
  });
```

Just a small help is needed,

Comment: You should share the minimum code required to replicate your problem. Otherwise we can't help you

Comment: Can you create JSBin, codepen or something similar with your code.

Comment: you guys don't even know how to add fadeIn fadeOut in this code? Actually my code is too heavy

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 Do not recommend users to share code from external links. Those links can become unavailable and other future users searching for this problem won't be able to access that code. There is a StackOverflow code snippet available ( Ctrl + M or the `<>` button in the top toolbar when writing/editing a question or an answer )

Comment: mr tanmay. We know a lot of stuff. You just need to take the time to make a working snippet with the MINIMUM code necessary to replicate your problem. Not the whole ( heavy ) code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a very basic implementation of fadeIn and fadeOut;

Since your code wasn't complete; I created my own;

Hope this helps

```js
 $("button").click(function(){                
        $("#dog1").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#dog3").fadeIn("slow");
    });
```

```css
#dog3 {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b0/d7/08/b0d708c285de860ce5d51a8d558409dc.jpg" width ="100px" height="100px" id="dog1">
<img src="https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Common-dog-behaviors-explained.jpg?itok=FSzwbBoi" width ="100px" height="100px" id="dog3">
<button> Fade Images </button>
```